# Log sql statments/queries executed by HugSQL

Tags: logging, clojure, hugsql

I want to log all SQL strings executed by HugSQL. I looked through the docs, but couldn't find anything. Whats the recommended way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it myself by digging around the hugsql source. It works similar to converting the result set of a generated function (https://github.com/layerware/hugsql/issues/21):

```
(defn log-sqlvec [sqlvec]
  (log/info (->> sqlvec
              (map #(clojure.string/replace (or % "") #"\n" ""))
              (clojure.string/join " ; "))))

(defn log-command-fn [this db sqlvec options]
  (log-sqlvec sqlvec)
  (condp contains? (:command options)
    #{:!} (hugsql.adapter/execute this db sqlvec options)
    #{:? :<!} (hugsql.adapter/query this db sqlvec options)))

(defmethod hugsql.core/hugsql-command-fn :! [sym] `log-command-fn)
(defmethod hugsql.core/hugsql-command-fn :<! [sym] `log-command-fn)
(defmethod hugsql.core/hugsql-command-fn :? [sym] `log-command-fn)
```

Comment: Where should I put that code? I'm clojure newbie using Luminus, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I put it in my `db.clj`. I believe you can put this anywhere you like as long as it gets executed (for example by requiring a ns).

Answer (score 2):

Per the HugSQL doc:

> HugSQL generates a format internally known as **sqlvec**. The **sqlvec** format is a vector with an SQL string in the first position containing any `?` placeholders, followed by any number of parameter values to be applied to the SQL in positional order.
>
> ...
>
> HugSQL provides the `hugsql.core/def-sqlvec-fns` macro to create functions returning the **sqlvec** format. The created functions have an `-sqlvec` suffix by default, though this is configurable with the `:fn-suffix` option. These functions are helpful during development/debugging and for the purpose of using the parameter-replacing functionality of HugSQL without using the built-in adapter database functions to execute queries.

So you could use the `sqlvec` version of the functions colocated with where you call your HugSQL functions to log out the SQL that would be executed.

The doc actually provides the following example.  Given that you've loaded HugSQL queries like so:

```
(ns princess-bride.db.characters
  (:require [hugsql.core :as hugsql]))

(hugsql/def-db-fns "princess_bride/db/sql/characters.sql")
(hugsql/def-sqlvec-fns "princess_bride/db/sql/characters.sql")
```

And given the following function call:

```
(characters/characters-by-ids-specify-cols db
  {:ids [1 2], :cols ["name" "specialty"]})
```

You can get at the generated sqlvec with the following:

```
(characters/characters-by-ids-specify-cols-sqlvec
  {:ids [1 2], :cols ["name" "specialty"]})
```

Which would return something like:

```
["select name, specialty from characters
  where id in (?,?)",1,2]
```

Comment: This is does not log executed SQL strings.